# How to set watchpoint on a variable, to break only when it decreases

Tags: debugging, gdb

I want to monitor a variable for when it decreases. How can I do it in GDB?

Comment: Welcome to [stackoverflow] (http://stackoverflow.com/tour) please share what you have tried. then if you got stucked with some exact issue, we will help you. Refer these links for asking proper questions (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , (http://stackoverflow.com//help/mcve) and (http://sscce.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a combination of watchpoints, conditions, and convenience variables.

The basic idea is to put a condition on the watchpoint that triggers only when the value decreases.

As a simple example, here is how you would see if a variable goes below some specific value:

```
(gdb) watch -location variable if variable < 53
```

You could implement a sort of "ratchet" like this:

```
(gdb) set $save = variable
(gdb) watch -location variable if variable < $save && ($save = variable, 1)
```

This should break when the variable goes beneath the saved value.

However, this isn't the same as breaking on decrement.  For that, you have to watch all changes to the variable.  One way would be:

```
(gdb) set $save = variable
(gdb) watch -location variable if $copy = $save, $save = variable, variable < $copy
```